# How to make a secure silent authentication in Rails & react js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication

I'm working on a simple frontend in react js and a backend in rails. The frontend is made up of 2 parts :

- Some pages (/home, /about, ...) which do not need a login but it needs to get data from the rails-api. To make things secure I added an authentication in the frontend code below : (i don't know whether that fits best practices).

```
       ...
       const url = endpoint+"tokens"
       const credentials = {user: {email: "frontend@email.com", password: "mypassword" }}
       const result = await axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(credentials), {
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
       });
       authorization = { key : result.data.token ,  expiredTime : result.data.expirationTime}
       ...
```

- Dashboard (/login) with login page to manage the database content

The rails backend Controllers check every request with 'before_action :check_login' to make sur that user is logged in before execute any action on the database.

Comment: anybody to help

Comment: Its very unclear what your problem is here. If you have routes that don't require the user to be authenticated then don't require authentication. Problem solved.